# bower dependency version bounds (/semver)

Tags: dependencies, versioning, package, bower

I've been trying to write dependencies into my **bower.json** but whenever I use comparators (`>` or `<`) or the wildcard `*`, I just get the message `blah blah blah incompatible with *` or something similar when I use `bower list`.

For example:

```
"requirejs": ">2.0.0"
```

I get `requirejs#2.1.8 incompatible with >2.0.0` as an error.

Similarly, if I try:

```
"backbone": "*"
```

I get `backbone#1.0.0 incompatible with *`.

I don't want to fix my versions at the patch number, only really at the major number. Is there any way to do this? I've found the bower/semver documentation distinctly unhelpful.

### update

so weirdly it seems to have started working for no reason that I can fathom, I haven't changed anything (but perhaps have updated Bower).

Comment: Could you include the complete output of `bower list` (showing `requirejs`, `backbone` and everything that depends on them)?

Comment: It seems to have started working, but I don't know why. I may have updated Bower recently so that may have fixed it...